# Universal and strong $Q$-sets

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing

A subset $X\subset \mathbb R$ is called

$\bullet$ a *$Q$-set* if for every subset $A\subset X$ there exists a $\sigma$-compact set $C\subset\mathbb R$ such that $C\cap X=A$;

$\bullet$ a *strong $Q$-set* if for every Polish subspace $P\subset \mathbb R$ and every subset $A\subset X\cap P$ there exists a $\sigma$-compact set $C\subset P$ such that $C\cap X=A$;

$\bullet$ a *universal $Q$-set* if for every continuous injective map $f:P\to \mathbb R$ form a Polish space $P$ and every subset $A\subset f^{-1}(X)$ there exists a $\sigma$-compact set $C\subset P$ such that $C\cap f^{-1}(X)=A$.

It is clear that $$\mbox{countable $\Rightarrow$ universal $Q$-set $\Rightarrow$ strong $Q$-set $\Rightarrow$ $Q$-set}.$$

It can be shown that every $Q$-set $X\subset\mathbb R$ of cardinality $X\le \mathfrak b$ is a universal $Q$-set.

Let $\mathfrak q_0$ be the smallest cardinality $|X|$ of a subset $X\subset \mathbb R$ which is not a $Q$-set. It [is known](http://journals.iapmm.lviv.ua/ojs/index.php/MBSSS/article/view/522/974) that $$\mathfrak p\le\mathfrak q_0\le \min\{\mathfrak b,\mathrm{non}(\mathcal N)\}.$$

Using the inequality $\mathfrak q_0\le\mathfrak b$, it can be shown that every subset $X\subset\mathbb R$ of cardinality $|X|<\mathfrak q_0$ is a universal $Q$-set. So, $\mathfrak q_0$ coincides with the smallest cardinality of a subset $X\subset \mathbb R$ which fails to be a strong (or universal) $Q$-set.

Let $\mathfrak q$ (resp. $\mathfrak{q_s}$, $\mathfrak q_u$) be the smallest cardinal $\kappa$ such that every subset $X\subset\mathbb R$ of cardinality $|X|\ge\kappa$ is not a (resp. strong, universal) $Q$-set. It can be shown that $$\mathfrak q_0\le \min\{\mathfrak b,\mathfrak q\}\le\mathfrak q_u\le\mathfrak q_s\le \mathfrak q\le\log(\mathfrak c^+),$$where $\log(\mathfrak c^+):=\min\{\kappa:2^\kappa>\mathfrak c\}$. So, under $2^{\omega_1}>\mathfrak c$, $\mathfrak q=\omega_1$, which means that every $Q$-set is countable.

The consistency of the strict inequality $\mathfrak q_0=\mathfrak b<\mathfrak q$ was proved by [Judah and Shelah](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1991-111-03/S0002-9939-1991-1045594-5/S0002-9939-1991-1045594-5.pdf).

> **Problem.** Which of the strict inequalities $\mathfrak q_0<\mathfrak q_u$, $\mathfrak q_u<\mathfrak q_s$, $\mathfrak q_s<\mathfrak q$ are contistent?